# how to change color using find and replace method in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

There is an output of html/css code like below.

```
<ul>
<li>Capacity : 1.000 kg</li>
<li>Load Capacity When Extended : 1.000 kg</li>
<li>Max. Number of users (indoor/outdoor) : 4</li>
</ul>
```

I want javascript to do this. "If there is a ":" in the <li>, let the color be red, including the ":".

Short information: Since it pulls the above ul/li event from the database, I need to add js to make it a forced page.
Thanks to everyone who took the time.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycs6M.png)

Comment: The colour of all the text inside the `li`?

Comment: The linked duplicate does exactly what you want, you just need to move the code outside of a button's click event handler.

Comment: like this [link] (https://r.resimlink.com/Dz-04vo.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const checkIfTwoPoints = (el) => {
  const els = el.querySelectorAll('li');
  els.forEach(e => {
    const str = e.innerHTML;
    let ix = str.indexOf(':');
    if (ix > -1) {
      // substring +2, according spaces between :
      e.innerHTML = '<span class="make-red">' + str.substring(0, ix + 2) + '</span><span class="make-bold">' + str.substring(ix + 2) + '</span>';
    }
  })
}

const myUl = document.querySelector('.myUl')
checkIfTwoPoints(myUl);
```

```css
.make-red {
  color: red;
}

.make-bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<ul class="myUl">
  <li>Capacity : 1.000 kg</li>
  <li>Load Capacity When Extended : 1.000 kg</li>
  <li>Max. Number of users (indoor/outdoor)</li>
  <li>Max. Number of users (indoor/outdoor) : 4</li>
</ul>
```

I've edited the snippet, red before the : plus the :, for fun bold after

Comment: Thanks for your help how do I get it to look like this? https://r.resimlink.com/Dz-04vo.png

Comment: edited check the modified snippet